как закастомить pagination в swiper




import React from "react";
import s from "./index.module.scss";
import stars from "assets/vectors/featuredProperties/starts.svg";
import arrow from "assets/vectors/featuredProperties/arrow.svg";

import img1 from "assets/img/featuredProperties/01.png";
import img2 from "assets/img/featuredProperties/02.png";
import img3 from "assets/img/featuredProperties/03.png";

import bed from "assets/vectors/featuredProperties/bed.svg";
import bath from "assets/vectors/featuredProperties/bath.svg";
import house from "assets/vectors/featuredProperties/house.svg";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper/modules";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import SwiperCore from "swiper";

SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination]);

export const FeaturedProperties: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <section className={s.featuredPropertiesBg}>
      <div className="container">
        <div className={s.featuredProperties}>
          <img src={stars} alt="stars" />
          <div className={s.info}>
            <h1 className={s.infoTitle}>Featured Properties</h1>
            <div className={s.bottom}>
              <p>
                Explore our handpicked selection of featured properties. Each listing offers a
                glimpse into exceptional homes and investments available through Estatein. Click
                "View Details" for more information.
              </p>
              <button>
                <a href="#">View All Properties</a>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={s.carousel}>
            <Swiper
              pagination={{
                type: "fraction",
                el: ".custom-pagination",
              }}
              navigation={{
                nextEl: ".customNext",
                prevEl: ".customPrev",
              }}
              modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
              spaceBetween={30}
              slidesPerView={1}
              className={s.swiperContainer}
            >
              <SwiperSlide>
                <div className={s.cards}>
                  <div className={s.card}>
                    <img src={img1} alt="img1" />
                    <h3>Seaside Serenity Villa</h3>
                    <p className={s.description}>
                      A stunning 4-bedroom, 3-bathroom villa in a peaceful suburban neighborhood...
                      <a href="#">Read More</a>
                    </p>
                    <div className={s.details}>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bed} alt="bed" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>4-Bedroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bath} alt="bath" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>3-Bathroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={house} alt="house" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>Villa</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={s.selling}>
                      <div className={s.price}>
                        <p className={s.text}>Price</p>
                        <p className={s.value}>$550,000</p>
                      </div>
                      <button>
                        <a href="">View Property Details</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className={s.card}>
                    <img src={img2} alt="img2" />
                    <h3>Metropolitan Haven</h3>
                    <p className={s.description}>
                      A chic and fully-furnished 2-bedroom apartment with panoramic city views...
                      <a href="#">Read More</a>
                    </p>
                    <div className={s.details}>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bed} alt="bed" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>2-Bedroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bath} alt="bath" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>2-Bathroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={house} alt="house" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>Villa</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={s.selling}>
                      <div className={s.price}>
                        <p className={s.text}>Price</p>
                        <p className={s.value}>$550,000</p>
                      </div>
                      <button>
                        <a href="">View Property Details</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className={s.card}>
                    <img src={img3} alt="img3" />
                    <h3>Rustic Retreat Cottage</h3>
                    <p className={s.description}>
                      An elegant 3-bedroom, 2.5-bathroom townhouse in a gated community...
                      <a href="#">Read More</a>
                    </p>
                    <div className={s.details}>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bed} alt="bed" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>3-Bedroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bath} alt="bath" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>3-Bathroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={house} alt="house" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>Villa</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={s.selling}>
                      <div className={s.price}>
                        <p className={s.text}>Price</p>
                        <p className={s.value}>$550,000</p>
                      </div>
                      <button>
                        <a href="">View Property Details</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </SwiperSlide>
              <SwiperSlide>
                <div className={s.cards}>
                  <div className={s.card}>
                    <img src={img1} alt="img1" />
                    <h3>Seaside Serenity Villa</h3>
                    <p className={s.description}>
                      A stunning 4-bedroom, 3-bathroom villa in a peaceful suburban neighborhood...
                      <a href="#">Read More</a>
                    </p>
                    <div className={s.details}>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bed} alt="bed" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>4-Bedroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bath} alt="bath" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>3-Bathroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={house} alt="house" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>Villa</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={s.selling}>
                      <div className={s.price}>
                        <p className={s.text}>Price</p>
                        <p className={s.value}>$550,000</p>
                      </div>
                      <button>
                        <a href="">View Property Details</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className={s.card}>
                    <img src={img2} alt="img2" />
                    <h3>Metropolitan Haven</h3>
                    <p className={s.description}>
                      A chic and fully-furnished 2-bedroom apartment with panoramic city views...
                      <a href="#">Read More</a>
                    </p>
                    <div className={s.details}>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bed} alt="bed" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>2-Bedroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bath} alt="bath" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>2-Bathroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={house} alt="house" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>Villa</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={s.selling}>
                      <div className={s.price}>
                        <p className={s.text}>Price</p>
                        <p className={s.value}>$550,000</p>
                      </div>
                      <button>
                        <a href="">View Property Details</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className={s.card}>
                    <img src={img3} alt="img3" />
                    <h3>Rustic Retreat Cottage</h3>
                    <p className={s.description}>
                      An elegant 3-bedroom, 2.5-bathroom townhouse in a gated community...
                      <a href="#">Read More</a>
                    </p>
                    <div className={s.details}>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bed} alt="bed" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>3-Bedroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={bath} alt="bath" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>3-Bathroom</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className={s.items}>
                        <img src={house} alt="house" />
                        <p className={s.detailsText}>Villa</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={s.selling}>
                      <div className={s.price}>
                        <p className={s.text}>Price</p>
                        <p className={s.value}>$550,000</p>
                      </div>
                      <button>
                        <a href="">View Property Details</a>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </SwiperSlide>
            </Swiper>
          </div>
          <div className={s.pagination}>
            <div className={`custom-pagination ${s.customPagination}`}></div>
            <div className={s.arrows}>
              <div className={s.customNext}>
                <img src={arrow} alt="arrow" />
              </div>
              <div className={s.customPrev}>
                <img src={arrow} alt="arrow" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};



в общем как мне сделать то что в дизайне ? а именно сделайть of  и сделать его отедльным цветом + как на стрелках переключения сделать так что бы одна была полупрозрачной пока мы находимся на 1 странице ?
Заранее спасибо за ответ ! <3

Пример


const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: "fraction",
    bulletActiveClass: 'swiper-pagination-bullet-active',
    renderFraction: function(currentClass, totalClass) {
      return `<span class="${currentClass}"></span>
                    <span class="swiper-pagination-divider">off</span>
              <span class="${totalClass}"></span>`
    }
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
.swiper {
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.swiper .swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.swiper-pagination-divider {
  color: #f00;
}

.swiper:has(.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-disabled) .swiper-pagination-current,
.swiper:has(.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-disabled) .swiper-pagination-current {
  color: #00f;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>


<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>



https://v9.swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-pagination-renderFraction
